# How to optimize an algorithm that prints n prime numbers

Tags: ruby, optimization, primes

I'm hoping someone can help me optimize this algorithm. This solution does what I want in irb, but times out on the codewars site.

```
class Primes
  def self.first(n)
    arr = []

    i ||= 2

    until arr.length == n

      is_prime = true

      (2..(i**0.5)).step do |num|
        if i % num == 0
          is_prime = false
          break
        end
      end

      arr << i if is_prime == true

      i += 1

    end

    arr
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered giving a shot at the [benchmarking standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)?

Comment: Two minor suggestions: `is_prime` is useless. `i` can be incremented by 2 for each iteration.

Comment: Is this the exact code you are submitting? `is_prime` is not defined ahead of time here and gives an error when executing this code as written.

Comment: Great catch - you are totally right. is_prime has to be defined ahead of time. I realized after I submitted that code snippet. Sorry about that everyone

Comment: @aetherus, I tried incrementing by 2 and I ran into problems. My terminal stalled for some reason

Comment: See my solution. Note that the only even prime is 2, so you can pre-populate your `prime_array` with 2, then start the loop and increment `i` by 2.

Answer (score 2):

I think this implementation is one of the fastest you can possibly get:

```
require 'prime'

Primes = Prime # so that we have the same interface as in your question
```

And … we're done. That's all there is to do.

`Prime` is `Enumerable`, so we can now just do

```
Primes.first(10_000)
```

to get the first 10 000 primes.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to define `is_prime` initially so your code doesn't run.

Anyway, one thing you could do is drop `Math.sqrt` and instead calculate `num*num`. Generally speaking `Math.sqrt` is much slower than multiplication:

```
class Primes

  def self.first(n)

    prime_array = []

    i = 2

    until prime_array.length == n

      is_prime = true

      num = 2
      until num*num > i
        if i % num == 0
          is_prime = false
          break
        end
        num += 1
      end

      if is_prime != false
        prime_array << i
      end

      i += 1

    end

    prime_array

  end

end
```

Comment: sped up significantly by using multiplication instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to get the first n primes, not the first m primes less than or equal to n.

```
class Primes

  def self.first(n)
    return [] if n <= 0

    primes = [2]

    i = 3
    while primes.size < n
      primes.push(i) unless primes.any?{|p| i % p == 0}
      i += 2
    end

    primes

  end

end
```

Comment: Cool, I see. Thanks!